# Performing BLAST/SmithWaterman searches directly from my application

Tags: c, mpi, sequence, bioinformatics

I'm working on a small application and thinking about integrating BLAST or other local alignment searches into my application. My searching has only brought up programs, which need to be installed and called as an external program.

Is there a way short of me implementing it from scratch? Any pre-made library perhaps?

Comment: Addition: I know that re-implementing BLAST would be futile. I also can not use a interface to a blast running on the web, because I want to define my own library of sequences to align against. I would love to find a library which offers blast and smith-waterman and possibly other alignment algorithms, which can be called from my code without having to write my sequences out to an input file and starting a system call with complicated parameters to run the alignments.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to make 'system()' calls to a local copy of BLAST?

Comment: I don't want to write the sequences to a file, which is needed as input for those stand-alone programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just stumbled across the thing I would have wanted: [The NCBI C++ Toolkit](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/). Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be in C, or would C++ also be OK? If so, you might want to look at the SeqAn library [here](http://www.seqan.de/).

Comment: That's great. I'll take a look at it, if I can implement it in C++ too.

Answer (score 5):

This is a topic which has also to do with reproducibility of results: it is always better to use the raw blast binary provided by NCBI or UCSC, because it will make your results easeir to reproduce by other scientists and will save you a lot of time spent on writing tests (more time than you can imagine).

For the day-to-day work I have often used [exonerate](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/~guy/exonerate/), a tool written in C which can do both global and local alignment, has a simple unix-like interface, and doesn't require to format your input as with blast.

Moreover, take in mind that people usually use a combination of makefiles and scripts to define a pipeline, instead of calling everything from a script: most programming languages are not good to define pipelines, while automated build tools like Make are not useful for scripting tasks. Have a look at these examples: http://skam.sourceforge.net/skam-intro.html http://swc.scipy.org/lec/build.html

Answer (score 1):

The [BLAST](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2231712) algorithm was implemented ~20 years ago, it is now a very big algorithm and I cannot imagine it can be easily implemented from scratch.  You can try to learn about it when looking at the sources of the 'blastall' program in the [NCBI toolkit](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/).
A simpler [pairwise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment)  algorithm  (Swith Waterman, Needleman-Wunsch )should be easier to implement:

Answer (score 0):

[Computational Molecular Biology: An Introduction](http://cs.bc.edu/~clote/ComputationalMolecularBiology/) has code for [Smith-Waterman](http://cs.bc.edu/~clote/ComputationalMolecularBiology/Alignment/waterman.cc) and other dynamic programming alignment algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBLAST through the blastcl3 client binary. I believe that the blastcl3 binary is a pretty thin client for the NetBLAST web service.

If so, it shouldn't be too hard to sniff the packets and implement your own client. Depending on your use case, this might be faster/easier than implementing your own alignment algorithm. It does, however, introduce a dependency to NCBI's web services.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/staff/tao/URLAPI/netblast.html

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question ([running BLAST (bl2seq) without creating sequence files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248016/running-blast-bl2seq-without-creating-sequence-files))

Basically, the answer I came up with was running this command:

```
bl2seq -i<(echo sequence1) -j(echo sequence2) -p blastn
```

That pipes the result of the echo command to the bl2seq (blast 2 sequences) program.

But I couldn't get it to work via calling system from Python